# Xcode 4 breakpoint switches to "assistant view"

Tags: ios, xcode4

How to prevent switching from "standard view" to "editor view" in Xcode 4 when I'm debugging and hitting a breakpoint?

I want to remain in editor view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode Menu, Preferences, Behaviors Tab

The behaviors panels controls what windows show and which actions to take as different activities happen.

Under Run Starts there's different options to control which windows show.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I can't figure out how to do this (Xcode 4.5.2). Are you supposed to add a new rule or modify an existing one?

Comment: I just looked in 4.5.2 and under Xcode, preferences, behaviors tab, under the run section there's a bunch of show options you can check.  One in show ... "editor as" and you can select current, standard etc... There's other show options.